# SSRS <<expr>> error with sum

Tags: reporting-services

I have two equations on the same dataset. One returns an error, the other does not. The equations are as follows:

```
1) =Sum(IIF(Fields!Service.Value="Dispatch Only", 0, Fields!Charge.Value))
2) =Sum(IIF(Fields!Service.Value="DispatchOnly", 0, Fields!Charge.Value))
```

Note that the only difference between the two is the fact that I took a space out of the field I'm looking for.

I want a total sum of the entire data set. But then I also need to know what that same sum is, without the "Dispatch Only" values. Obviously, equation #2 doesn't produce any useful information (it's just the sum again), but I added it just to prove I wasn't insane with some very basic typo, like a comma out of place.

What am I doing wrong with equation #1??

[image: This is the result of two equations on the same dataset]

Comment: What's the underlying data type of `Charge`? You're probably getting a mismatch between that and `0` (i.e. an integer). Try replacing `0` with `CDec(0)`, `CDbl(0)`, or `Nothing` to try and resolve.

Comment: What happens if you add the name of the dataset as a 2nd argument to the Sum-function, as in: `=Sum(IIF(Fields!Service.Value="Dispatch Only", 0, Fields!Charge.Value),"DataSet1")`

Comment: Ian: That was it... it was a decimal. Please leave that as a true answer so that I can mark it as the answer and give you credit.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the update... Added as an answer. Was 99% sure it was the issue, but tough to reproduce without your data so hence originally posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This commonly occurs when applying an aggregate on differing data types, which you're unlikely to get unless you have an `IIf` statement, like in your example.

You're probably getting a mismatch between `Charge` and *0* (i.e. between the underlying data type of `Charge` and the integer *0*).

To get around this, make sure that *0* is the same data type as `Charge`, i.e. use something like `CDec(0)` or `CDbl(0)` as required.

One other option to consider is to use `Nothing` in place of *0* - by using the SSRS null value you avoid any data type clashes, but it does have the disadvantage of returning `Nothing` if there are no matching *Dispatch Only* rows.